# Javascript Regex - Remove Chars, WhiteSpace & Starting 0

Tags: javascript, regex

I have hit a brick wall with this one....

I have managed to remove the Chars, but looking for the removal of all WhiteSpaces, Carrige Returns & the 0's at the start of each entry after the Chars have been removed.

```
var p_string = 'OPS010001 BLW020002 MKS030003';
var p_data = p_string.split(/[^0-9]+/g);

$('body').html(p_data + '<BR>');
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vs7xe/14/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like this

```
var p_data = p_string.split(/[^0-9]+/g).map(function(x){

  return x.replace(/^0|\s/g, ""); // remove space, carriage return and 0 at start

}); // you can use Array.join to join the array with separator of your choice
```

Comment: I have amended my script now, but I have 1 issue now if you can help. When it removes a Char from the Start, it puts a space, which means a Semicolon is added at the start. http://jsfiddle.net/vs7xe/20/

Comment: @timeismoney do you want it or not?

Comment: Dont want the ; at the Start, looks like it is adding a blank value in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Use `string.replace` function.

```
string.replace(/^0|\s/g, "");
```

`\s` matches white space characters including line breaks.

Comment: @a didn't knew that. Will you mind if I edited my answer to `\s`?